# I have coded a spark job to run on local mode but when I submit that job I run it on yarn cluster mode. What exactly happens in this case?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, bigdata

I see that the status is ACCEPTED. It doesn't change to RUNNING state. After a timeout it fails. I have attached an image which shows exactly the same. Inside the job I have been saving some data in a Cassandra table. The job doesn't go in RUNNING state, however the table is getting updated till the job doesn't timeout. I am not able to understand what exactly is happening under the hood.[image]

Comment: There is an **error message** there. Did you try fixing your `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the application with master as local

```
spark-submit --master local[2] application
```

Maybe your default configuration  will be run  the application on yarn cluster. Since yarn cluster is not initialized it is giving NullpointException.